# How to prevent the upload button from selecting a file over a particular size and type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to prevent users from selecting a file that is over 50kB. If the user selects a file the js function does the validation and sets the value of the upload function to 0. The code does everything I intend it to do; however, when the function is completed, the change of value does not reflect on the HTML element.

I have been through numerous Stack Overflow posts and most of them say to set the value of the upload file to "null" or "0", which does not seem to work for me.

```
      <p>Hello World</p>
      <button>Change color</button>
      <br><br>
      <input type="file" id="myFile" />
   </div>
```

Lines 1 - 6 /file.html

```
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){
  banner.addClass("alt")
})



$('#myFile').bind('change', function() {

    b = this.value;
    a = this.files[0].size/1024;
    fileName = this.files[0];
    //this.files[0].size gets the size of your file.
    //alert(a);
    alert(b);

    if(a > 50){
      alert(fileName.name);
      alert("Greater than 50Kb");
      //alert(c);
      b = null;
      alert(b);
    } else {
      alert("Lesser than 50Kb");
    }

alert(b);
});
```

Lines 10 - 41 /validate.js

What I want to happen is, when the function runs and does the validation, the value of the HTML element should be removed and it should show me a fresh HTML element with no values saying "No file chosen" if it does not satisfy the criteria. Please help, your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried doing `this.value = null`? Not sure why that wouldn't work.

Comment: I did not initially, but I did after you suggested and it worked. Thanks for your help mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just changing the value of the variable `b` from `this.value` to `null`. Try using `this.value = null` as think123 suggested.